# Problems with Ratchet websoket

Tags: apache, ssl, websocket, ratchet

I have some problems with Ratchet websoket server when I'm trying to use it with web application when I turn SSL on.

I tried to use Apache mod_proxy_wstunnel.so and stunnel both, but it has no result.

Maybe I did something wrong, but my Ratchet still doesn't work with JavaScript client over SSL. When I turn SSL off, everything works perfectly.

Due to my task, I must use SSL in my project.

Apache 2.4.12
Red Hat Linux Server 6.5

Here is Apache my mod_proxy_wstunnel.so configs:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine           on
ServerName mydomain.com
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass "/ws/"  "ws://mydomain.com:8098"
ProxyPass "/wss/"  "wss://mydomain.com:8098"
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my stunnel configs (I used it separately with mod_proxy_wstunnel.so):

```
[websockets]
accept = 443
connect = 8098
```